# Sorting using min heap with merging duplicate keys

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heapsort

I have a data which I read and insert in min heap. The node inserted has a key a count and a value. The use of count is to merge all same keys and store the count of duplicate keys in one node. So if key1 is in source data three times I want the data to become key1 with count as 3. One way is to keep inserting duplicate keys too and while removing from heap all same keys will come out back to back. But is there a better way where while inserting in the minheap I can merge the duplicate keys?

Comment: You could use a binary search tree instead of the heap. Or just sort the data and then in a second pass combine the duplicates. But what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: Problem with that is that it can get skewed and will start behaving like a linked list

Comment: There are several kinds of balanced trees guaranteeing O(log n) behaviour for inserts and deletes.

Comment: There is no efficient way to merge the items while inserting into the min heap. Your choices are to remove the duplicates before insertion, remove during the sort, or remove after the sort, as suggested, or remove in a separate pass afterwards.